# Adding multiple objects to a user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, migration, models

I previously asked a vague question about adding multiple objects to a user table. I got a really good answer from heading_to_tahiti but I am having trouble implementing it.

I have my user migration all set up with devise. I wanted to be able to make a form that allows a user to add a medications to their account. He suggested making a medications model and other stuff using scaffolding and making a medication column in the user model. I tried this and its on the right track but I'm confused on how the medications model does anything and how the medication column stores multiple medications.

I am a newbie at rails and especially at doing anything server related, so any help would be appreciated.

I want the end result to be this web portal showing all of the users' medications and allowing them to do the CRUD tasks on them. I hope this isn't too far-reached and definitely don't feel obligated to answer the whole question, I know this is a lot to ask for.

Here is the previous question [How can I add additional columns to a Users table with rails and devise gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545084/how-can-i-add-more-columns-to-a-users-table-with-rails)

And my app currently https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWGfS.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a one-to-many relationship. One user can have many medications. Create a model for your medications that has a field called `user_id`. In `medications.rb`:

```
class Medication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and in `users.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :medications
end
```

As long as your medications model has a field called `user_id`, Rails is smart enough to know that when you call `myuser.medications` you want all of the `Medication` records where `user_id = myuser.id`. You can [read more here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Thanks I think that will work! I won't be able to test it out until tomorrow so I will update you then. I don't have enough rep to upvote comments so I can only accept the answer, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused on the myuser.medications part though. How can I call that? I have a user table so where does the "my" part come from?

Comment: It's just a placeholder that could be any user. `myuser = User.find(1)` for example